# Why are some ARRAYS written like this in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

I just wanted to know why are some arrays written like this?

`int arr[] = {3, 4, 6, 9, 11};`

Why can't it just be written like this instead?

`int arr[5] = {3, 4, 6, 9, 11}`

What's the benefit?

Comment: The first one let's you omit the number, so you don't have to count how many elements you have. Makes it easier to add/remove elements as well.

Comment: To repeat what Ted said, you gain flexibility. The second example would be considered "brittle" because now a change to the elements of the array requires at least one other manual change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why can't it just be written like this instead?

The premise is wrong. It can be written both ways.

> What's the benefit?

The size is redundant information. We've already implicitly given the size 5 by providing 5 initialisers. Providing redundant information is a potential source of bugs during development when that information accidentally goes out of sync.

For example, if the programmer decides later that the last 11 wasn't supposed to be there and should be removed leaving 4 elements in the array, the programmer making that change might not notice that the size has to also be changed, leading to a case where the last element is not removed as intended but replaced with value initialised element instead.

If the size of the array is supposed to be the same  as the number of initialisers, then it is safer to not specify that size explicitly. To not specify the size explicitly is to follow the *"Don't Repeat Yourself"* principle.

On the other hand, if the size of the array is always supposed to be 5 regardless of the number of initialisers, then specifying the size explicitly achieves that. I suspect that this case is rarer in practice (except when there are no initialisers at all). Note that you should probably use a constant variable instead of a magic number for the size.

Answer (score 1):

When you don't write any number into brackets, it means the array will have size equal to count of elements intialized with.

When you put there some number, you are giving the array a size.

```c
int arr[] = {1, 7, 5}; // Size of the array is 3

int arr[3] = {1, 7, 5}; // Size of the array is 3

int arr[5] = {1, 7, 5}; // Size of the array is 5
```

Declaring with defined size is good when you know that you will need this count of items, but you don't have the items yet.
Without defined size it is simply easier to write.